# fatal error: linux/err.h: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, kernel, c

What package should install for this header (`err.h`) is available?

I need this library (`linux/err.h`) to compile a proprietary driver (kernel module) in Ubuntu 14.04 Server/Desktop 64bits

Answer (score 0):

I think the package you want is `linux-libc-dev` . I encountered this when building 32-on-64; so I needed `linux-libc-dev:i386`.

Try running the following in a new Terminal window :

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev linux-headers-generic`